# Why does moment().format() create a date object six hours in the future?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Why when I use moment().format() on my local machine, does it create a date object that is six hours ahead of my local time? I'm Mountain Standard Time if it matters...

Comment: Well, mountain time is UTC-6... Odd coincidence.

Comment: Everywhere I've read online including this site says moment().format() translates into your browser's local time. This is not the case?

Comment: It's your local time in UTC format.   https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/  Scroll down to "Default format"

Comment: check the time zone of your computer. It may be set to UTC + 6 hours

Comment: @Amy - Ah, thank you. I'll accept your answer if you post it.

Comment: @darkknight - I'd notice if my computer's clock was incorrect very quickly since I view it several times per day.

Comment: @KSwift87 Maybe it adjusts itself when you  look. lol.... ;)

Comment: @darkknight No, his computer clock is fine.  It's giving him the time in UTC format, which will appear to be six hours ahead because he is six hours behind.

Answer (score 0):

From the [moment.js docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/):

> By default, moment parses and displays in local time

However, by default moment.js uses the ISO8601 format `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ`, where Z is your local [time offset from UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_offsets_from_UTC).

Here is an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLjQx/113862/).

Comment: I'm creating a new Date object by using moment().format().

Comment: What output do you get from moment().local().format()?

Comment: `format()` will *always* print the date in UTC format if not provided a format string.  It doesn't matter how you get the `moment` object.  Read the docs on the `format()` function.

Comment: I didn't know how the ISO8601 format worked with the z offset. I guess technically it's being displayed in local time as-is.

Comment: I found some conversion code being used by the HTML template that was throwing things off, because after feeding .format() a format string, I was still getting the same issue.

Comment: @Amy I don't think that is correct. Moment.js displays local times for me -- see the JSFiddle in my answer.